# Phusion passenger-status active count is always pointing to zero

Tags: apache, passenger, phusion

I have installed phusion passenger 3 in my apache, which has a memory limit of 5GB and swap of 2GB, when i check the passenger status in the general information the active row always shows zero where as count will be 2 to 3 and inactive will be upto 6.

But my memory usage has crossed 4.8GB but still the active row is showing zero.

why so.. Please can anybody help me on this

It is like:-

active   = 0
inactive = 6
Waiting on global queue: 0

The active row will always point to zero

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

`active` means that those processes exist, but are currently not handling any requests. If your site is idle then it's supposed to be 0.